# Calling a method from another class in message handler

Tags: c++, methods, call

I have .H file and .Cpp file for a dialog Print that contains two buttons Printer 1 and Printer 2 and I want to call a method in another class function when Printer 1 is pressed.
.H File

```
#pragma once
#ifndef PRINTCHOOSEDLG_H
#define PRINTCHOOSEDLG_H
class CPrintChooseDlg : public CTungstenDlg
{


public:

CPrintChooseDlg(CWnd* pParent = NULL);
enum { IDD = IDD_PRINTBOX };


protected:
    virtual void DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX);
    protected:
    afx_msg void OnPrinter1();
    afx_msg void OnPrinter2();

    //virtual void OnPrinter1();
    //virtual void OnPrinter2();
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
};

#endif
```

.Cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Tungsten.h"
#include "PrintChooseDlg.h"



CPrintChooseDlg::CPrintChooseDlg(CWnd* pParent /*=NULL*/)
    : CDialog(CPrintChooseDlg::IDD, pParent)
{

}


void CPrintChooseDlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialog::DoDataExchange(pDX);

}


BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CPrintChooseDlg, CDialog)
    ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_PRINTER1,OnPrinter1)
    ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_PRINTER2,OnPrinter2)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()




void CPrintChooseDlg::OnPrinter1()
{

    CTungstenDlg aux;
    aux.OnOK();

}
void CPrintChooseDlg::OnPrinter2()
{

    CTungstenDlg aux;
    aux.OnOK();

}
```

How can i call the method `CTungsten::OnOK` inside the function `CPrintChooseDlg::OnPrinter1()`

It gives me an error of course because it is not defined in the PrintChooseDlg.cpp

What i tried: is to include guards in header and use suggested solutions in comments
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Is `CTungsten::OnOK` declared in a header file?

Comment: Does Your class inherit from CTungsten?

Comment: when i include the header of the class where CTungsten is defined, I have this error: illegal call of non static member function

Comment: @Mike You need a `CTungsten` instance to call that function.

Comment: How can i do that. Syntax wise?

Comment: You have 2 ways to do that, first `class CPrintChooseDlg : CTungstenDlg` and then just `OnOK` or inside each printer function `CTungstenDlg aux; aux.OnOK`

Comment: I did the first option and i got the following errors: 
CPrintChooseDlg : class type redefinition
and fatal error: unexpected end of file found. I added the code up

Comment: @cparicio. any suggestions. I tried both solutions: I updated the Code Above

Comment: The line `class CPrintChooseDlg: CTungstenDlg{` should not be in the cpp file, only in the .h file

Comment: Well, The code now look like this, but then it gives more errors: like CTungstenDlg is undeclared identifier and more. I updated the .h file and the .cpp file above